# How can i change the font-size of my seaborn.displot graphic?

Tags: python, graph, graphics, seaborn

I'm trying to change the font-size of my graphic title in **seaborn.displot**.

I have this code:

```
f = sns.displot(df,x="yearOfRegistration", kde=True, binwidth=5)
f.set(title = "Distribuição de Veículos com base no Ano de Registro")
f.set_axis_labels("Ano de Registro","Densidade (KDE)")

plt.show()
```

My output goes:

[ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLgTI.png)

So, I tried this:

```
f = sns.displot(df,x="yearOfRegistration", kde=True, binwidth=5)
f.set(title = "Distribuição de Veículos com base no Ano de Registro", font_size = 20)
f.set_axis_labels("Ano de Registro","Densidade (KDE)")

plt.show()
```

And I have

> "AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no property 'font_size'"

I've looked all over the seaborn documentation and coudn't find the solution.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: `fontsize`.....

Comment: I tried fontsize but got the error:
"AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no property 'fontsize'"

Comment: Ah my mistake this is `displot` not `distplot`. `Displot` is a figure-level function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `pyplot`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.title("Title", fontdict = {'fontsize': 20})
```